# C# generic - returning objects of the derived class?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

```
public class BaseClass{
  public static T Find<T>(object value){
     -- db.get<T>("params", value);
  }
}

public class Derived: BaseClass{
}

...
void someMethod(){
  Derived obj = Derived.Find<Derived>(1);
}
```

In the above code how do I change `Derived obj = Derived.FindDerived<Derived>(1);` to `Derived obj = Derived.Find(1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method signature were something like this

```
public static T Find<T>(T value)
```

Then you could omit the type in the method call. However, from your given signature, the compiler is unable to infer the type without you stating it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases compiler can identify type parameters and they can be omitted but not in all cases. I think return value is just one of the not supported cases becase return value is not a part of the method signature.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx) is Eric Lippert's blog post on similar issue.

Comment: Compiler complains - Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Yes, you have to specify arguments explicitly, compiler cannot determine type parameter in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate it by changing BaseClass to a generic class:

```
public class BaseClass<T> {
    public static T Find(object value){
         -- db.get<T>("params", value);
    }
}

public class Derived: BaseClass<Derived> {

    void someMethod(){
      Derived obj = Derived.Find(1);
    }
}
```